# Using error_reporting with a string?

Tags: php

I am making a modification for a PHP software I use and I am wanting to allow users to enter  a custom error reporting level, such as `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

The issue is that the value they specifiy is saved as a string - and therefore I cannot reference it in the `error_reporting()` function.

Is there anyway I could convert the string into the value needed by the `error_reporting()` function? I have already tried the `constant()` function, however it says that the constant cannot be found.

Liam

Comment: Why would anyone like to do that?

Comment: that's not an explanation. There is a chance you're doing something in a terribly wrong way

Comment: @LiamW - I agree with zerkms; that's a *really* bizarre thing to want to do. I can't imagine any use-case where it would be sensible. The only reason for displaying errors is to assist developers working on the site. Typically therefore, on a dev system, you'd display all the errors, and on a live system you'd hide them all. To debug a live system, you should really be using the error log instead, but even if you do have a setting to view the errors, it should be single debug mode, rather than an open-ended ability to change core PHP flags, because that has "security hole" written all over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the main reason why `constant` isn't working for you here is because the string `'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE'` isn't a constant, but it's two constants and some bitwise operators. So what you could do here is use the `eval` function. However... be careful, be very careful.

An other way of going at it is getting all constants used in the string. You could use a regular expression for this:

```
$string = 'E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE';
$intval = 0;
preg_match_all('/[A-Z_]+/',$string, $constants);
//$constants looks like: array(array('E_ALL', 'E_NOTICE'))
foreach ($constants[0] as $key => $const)
{
    //either converts them to their value
    $constants[0][$key] = constant($const);
    //or replace them in the initial string
    //you can do this using preg_replace_callback, too of course
    $string = replace($const, constant($const), $string);
}
```

If you choose to replace the constant names with their values, you can at least make sure you're passing a slightly more secure string to `eval`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9&!|\^]/','',$string);//remove anything that isn't a number or bitwise operator.
error_reporting(eval($string));
```

However, if you don't want to use eval *at all*, you'll probably end up writing a `switch` in a function somewhere. That's not something I feel like doing for you, bit if you want to give it a shot:

```
//Get the constants
preg_match_all('/[A-Z_]/',$string,$constants);
//Get the bitwise operators
preg_match_all('[&|~^\s]', $string, $bitOps);

//eg:
$string= 'E_ALL& ~E_NOTICE ^FOOBAR';
//~~>
$constants = array( array ('E_ALL', 'E_NOTICE', 'FOOBAR'));
$bitops = array( array( ' & ~', ' ^'));//pay close attention to the spaces!
```

**Conclusion/My opinion:**
Why go through all this? It's slow, it's expensive, and insecure. A safer, simpler and easier solution IMHO would be *to store the int value, instead of a string*.
You want your clients to choose the `error_reporting` level (I can't see why...), why not create a `select` and give them a number of predefined options.

If you want to give them full control, allow them to use their own ini-file, but frankly: your goal should be to write your code in such a way that it runs under `E_STRICT | E_ALL`. If you do, there's not a lot of incentive to change `error_reporting`...
If you're allowing your clients to run their own code, and it's raising warnings or errors, please point out to them that *they shouldn't suppress, but FIX them!*

Comment: Very nice solution. The script is vBulletin, which uses eval() too much anyway. Also, this would be a back end option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the splitting part but I think you're able to do something like this:

```
$level = NULL;

// Modifications
$level = E_ALL;
$level &= ~E_NOTICE;

error_reporting($level);
```

And with putting conditions you can add preferred constants to your variable.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it simply by array:

```
        $string = "E_ALL";
        $errorLevel = array("E_ALL"     => E_ALL,
                            "E_NOTICE"  => E_NOTICE,
                            "E_ERROR"   => E_ERROR,
                            "E_WARNING" => E_WARNING,
                            "E_PARSE"   => E_PARSE);
        error_reporting($errorLevel[$string]);
```

Comment: And how would you handle `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` input?